# Select records in rectangle

Tags: postgresql

I have table in postgresql database with column `point` with type of `point`.

How can I select all records with point inside some rectangle with coordinates ((x1,y1),(x2,y2))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`@>` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-geometry.html#FUNCTIONS-GEOMETRY-OP-TABLE)

```
select *
from t
where box '((1,10),(5,10))' @> mypoint
```